# How to epoch EEG data with continuous stimuli for TRF analysis

Tags: continuous-signals, eeg

I'm running a study with continuous stimuli, I send triggers at the beginning and end of a period of recording (the time duration for each period is not fixed). I'm planning to analyse the data with temporal response function but not sure how to format the EEG data to epochs that correspond exactly to the stimuli. Can I use eeglab to retrieve the epochs somehow based on the onset and offset trigger or is there another way of doing this?

Any help on how to convert EEG data to CND structure would be welcome too!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to DSP.SE. Your question focuses more on programming aspect rather than a theoretical signal processing aspect. I would recommend that you have a look on the tutorial of EEGLAB, I am pretty sure they have examples on how to epoch data.